# Unable to run emulator after android build

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator

I have been trying to run the android emulator after building the android source code but I am not able to.  Here is what I have done:

```
$ source build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch full-eng
$ make -j4
```

The build runs fine, however I am not able to run the emulator after.

```
$ emulator
emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration!
```

From what I have read, the emulator that should be running should be in *out/host/linux-x86/bin/* however there is no *emulator* executable in that directory.  So I think its trying to start the wrong emulator?

```
$ which emulator
/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator

$ env | grep ANDROID
ANDROID_DEV_SCRIPTS=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/scripts:/home/kyle/AndroidSourc eRepo/prebuilts/devtools/tools
ANDROID_PRE_BUILD_PATHS=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin:
ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic
ANDROID_JAVA_TOOLCHAIN=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin
ANDROID_BUILD_TOP=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo
ANDROID_BUILD_PATHS=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/host/linux-x86/bin:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/emulator/qtools:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/scripts:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/devtools/tools:/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64:
ANDROID_QTOOLS=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/emulator/qtools
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/bin
ANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_2ND_ARCH=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/
ANDROID_EMULATOR_PREBUILTS=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64
ANDROID_HOST_OUT=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/host/linux-x86
ANDROID_SET_JAVA_HOME=true
```

Are there any suggestions?

```
$ emulator -verbose
emulator:Found ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic
emulator: Cannot find build properties file: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic/system/build.prop

emulator:Found build target architecture: <NULL>
emulator:Can't determine target AVD architecture: defaulting to arm
emulator:Using emulator-arm to emulate 'arm' CPUs
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/emulator64-arm
emulator:Probing for: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/libOpenglRender.so
emulator:Probing for: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/libOpenglRender.so
emulator:Probing for: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/lib/libOpenglRender.so
emulator:Probing for: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib64OpenglRender.so
emulator:Probing for: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib/lib64OpenglRender.so
emulator:Found OpenGLES emulation libraries in /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib
emulator:Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/android-emulator/linux-x86_64/lib:/opt/ros/hydro/lib:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mpirt/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/../compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/ipp/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/compiler/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/mkl/lib/intel64:/opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.0.080/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.4
emulator: found Android build root: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo
emulator: found Android build out:  /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic
emulator: Cannot find build properties file: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic/system/build.prop

emulator: Cannot find boot properties file: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic/boot.prop

emulator: Cannot find target CPU architecture, defaulting to 'arm'
emulator: Cannot find target CPU ABI, defaulting to 'armeabi'
emulator: Could not find target API sdkVersion / SDK version in build properties!
emulator: Default target API sdkVersion: 10000
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/tools/emulator/skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/hardware.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/kyle/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/development/tools/emulator/skins/HVGA/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/prebuilts/qemu-kernel/arm/kernel-qemu
emulator: WARNING: Could not determine kernel device naming scheme. Assuming legacy
If this AVD doesn't boot, and uses a recent kernel (3.10 or above) try setting
'kernel.newDeviceNaming' to 'yes' in its configuration.

emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -sysdir /home/kyle/AndroidSourceRepo/out/target/product/generic
emulator: ERROR: No initial system image for this configuration!
[1]+  Done                    emulator -avd avd1
```

It looks like some of the files are missing, although I'm not sure why that would happen if the source build was successful?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this locally. Are you sure the full build completed succesfully?

The error could be explained if the build was interrupted before the final system image was finalized.

Try using the -verbose option (i.e. "emulator -verbose"), this will print what the emulator is doing / which files it is probing, and give more details about what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will post what I get after doing the verbose option